# iOS, same size UIView show different size in different iphone？

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

I just write a very simple UIView(width :200, height：200), when I run in iphone XR and iphone 6 plus, obviously, the UIView on iphone 6 plus is bigger than iphone XR , why?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    UIView* view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 200, 200)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

Comment: @Sweeper, I put two iphone closely, actually the size is different, not a visual illusion.

Comment: Oops, turns out I was wrong. "Points" in iOS means something different. See [this](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions). You need to do some calculations to get the same physical size.

Comment: iPhone Xr have 414 points in width, iPhone 6 have 375 points, may be that is the case?

Comment: @Cy-4AH the UIView's width and height is fixed, 200*200

Comment: @zhouxinle devices have different ppi

Comment: @Cy-4AH, no, the value you write in codes is the actual phyhical size, not the px, ppi

Comment: @zhouxinle values you write in code is points, not mm, cm, dm, km

Answer (score 0):

Use below.

```
var iPhoneFactorX: CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width*1.00/1080.0)

UIView* view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100*iPhoneFactorX, 200*iPhoneFactorX, 200*iPhoneFactorX, 200*iPhoneFactorX)];
```

Now view will be same in all iPhone.

`1080` can be anything depending on designer give you size for the app screenshots.
We are using 1080 because designer give us 1080x1920 size screenshots for the app.

Comment: @zhouxinle : then change 200 with the required number